# How to remove a virus that trigger the internet explorer every some minutes?

Tags: windows-vista, anti-virus, virus, firewall, windows-live-messenger

Some days ago, I got a file in Windows Live Messenger by an account of my friend, I thought it was a normal file because he normally sent me some files as well. But this time, I had no luck, he got the virus from someone else.

I don't know what happens in my computer excepts that my computer hard disk runs as mad and every some minutes it trigger the internet explorer to launch some ads page, includes doubleclick, cam4, motor, etc....

How do I remove this virus from my computer? I don't have any virus program installed yet.
My computer os: Windows Vista, the Windows Firewall is disabled somehow that I could not reenable it.

Comment: First, you should read this other question: http://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware. If you still experience problems, don't hesitate to edit your question with more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download [Avira AntiVir Rescue System](http://www.free-av.com/en/tools/12/avira_antivir_rescue_system.html) and scan your computer then [search superuser for advice on free antivirus solutions](https://superuser.com/search?q=free+antivirus).

> Avira AntiVir Rescue System is a
>   Linux-based application that allows
>   accessing computers that cannot be
>   booted anymore. Thus it is possible
>   to:
>
> ```
> * repair a damaged system,
> * rescue data,
> * scan the system for virus infections.
> ```
>
> Just double-click on the rescue system
>   package to burn it to a CD/DVD. You
>   can then use this CD/DVD to boot your
>   computer.
>
> The Avira AntiVir Rescue System is
>   updated several times a day so that
>   the most recent security updates are
>   always available

Answer (score 1):

Try Malware Bytes AntiMalware or Spybot Search & Destroy which are specifically designed to remove such malware :)

Answer (score 1):

First, if you remember the date you opened that file from your friend (and btw, never do that again), try restoring Windows to a day before.

Second, install [Microsoft Security Essentials](http://www.microsoft.com/security_essentials/default.aspx) - free anti-virus/malware from MS.

Third, call your friend and have him do the same - chance are his machine was infected by a virus that goes through his contacts to perpetuate itself.
Good luck.